# The random variable X has density function given by... Calculate the expectation

Tags: probability, integration, expectation, gamma-function

[image: 1]

Can some one please explain to me how the Gamma is working/is being used here in this specific solution?

Im lost with this method...

Yes I am also aware it can be solved with substitution, but I want to know how this works!

Comment: Beta function in disguise: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: Wow thanks, I didnt even notice that, But how did the beta get modified on the second line then?

Comment: I just saw that Γ(a+1) =aΓ(a)!